# Broken pipe when trying to connect to MySQL 8.0.4 with PHP 7.2

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on a project that is needing to use some "bleeding edge" features coming with MySQL 8.0 (currently still in development).  I have been using MySQL 8.0.3 with no issue, but a recent release for MySQL 8.0.4 came out and now things are not working properly.  (The APT repos don't seem to allow installing 8.0.3 again, so am trying to find if my issues is something fixable before trying to build MySQL 8.0.3 from source.)

I have my database setup, and can use MySQL Workbench to make a connection to the database just fine (using the TCP/IP connection type with a username/password login).  Obviously workbench is not tailored for MySQL 8.0, but I can connect and do some basic things with tool.

However, when I try to connect to the database in PHP (just trying to initialize a connection with PDO), I am unable to connect.  I technically am working with Symfony and Doctrine, but also tried a basic test just creating a PDO object directly in a script.

When using Doctrine, I get an error of "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away" when trying to make the initial connection.

Doing some more debugging, I am also seeing an error of "Notice: PDO::__construct(): send of 133 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 43".

I'm thinking that there may be an issue with using the 8.0.4RC version of the DB, but the fact I can make a basic TCP/IP connection via the Workbench, I'd imagine then that there shouldn't be issues trying to connect in the same manner from other sources.

This is on a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 if that is relevant.

Comment: This tends to happen when using code that has not yet been properly tested. Its called _the bleeding edge_ for a reason

Comment: Understandable, I just find it odd that TCP/IP connections work fine in a product still not modified for use with the new database, but trying to connect via TCP/IP in another tool has issues.  Thought maybe it is something I am doing wrong and somebody else has experienced this and fixed it.